# Help me with the "or" jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this code:

```
$("#leftbutton").click(function(e){
 /// do xyz
});

$("#rightbutton").click(function(e){
 /// do xyz (same thing)
});
```

How do I combine them so that if you click #leftbutton or #rightbutton it does xyz?

Something like this:

```
$("#leftbutton OR #rightbutton").click(function(e){
 /// do xyz
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the comma, also known in the jQuery docs as the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector):

```
$("#leftbutton, #rightbutton").click(function(e){
 /// do xyz
});
```

Comment: ah ha! Thank you! It's hard to Google this one. The word "or" is just to vague.

Comment: For future reference: when you want to include a google keyword in your search, wrap it in quotes. For instance: jquery "or" selector

Comment: You can also use the plus sign: `+or`

Comment: btw, this is officially known as "selector grouping": http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Correct. The comma itself is technically not a selector, even though the jQuery docs call it one for some bizarre reason.

Answer (score 1):

Just like CSS selectors, you could use the comma

```
$("#leftbutton, #rightbutton").click(function(e){
 /// do xyz
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
$("#leftbutton, #rightbutton").click(function(e){
  ...
});
```